# How to make the whole table row clickable

Tags: angular

I have a common component class for creating a table. I'll share the code below.Below code is my .ts code

```
ngOnChanges(value: any) {
    if (value.inputColumns) {
      this.displayedColumns = (value.inputColumns.currentValue || []).filter(x => x.key != 'Actions');
      let changedColumns = (this.displayedColumns || []).map(obj => obj.key);
      if (value.inputButtons != null && value.inputButtons.currentValue.length > 0)
        changedColumns.push('Actions')
      this.columnsToDisplay = changedColumns;
      this.extraColumns = (value.inputColumns.currentValue || []).filter(x => x.key == 'Actions');
    }
    if (value.inputSource) {
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
      this.dataSource = value.inputSource.currentValue;
      this.dataLength = (value.inputSource.currentValue != null || value.inputSource.currentValue != undefined) ? value.inputSource.currentValue.length : 0;
    }
    if (value.inputMeta) {
      this.metaData = value.inputMeta.currentValue || new Meta();
    }
    if (value.inputButtons) {
      this.actionButton = value.inputButtons.currentValue || [];
      //this.actionButton = value.inputColumns.currentValue || [];
    }
  }
  onToggleClick(action: string, data: any, column: string) {
    const actionObj = {
      action,
      data,
      column
    }
    this.onTableActionClick.emit(actionObj);
  }
  onActionClick(action: string, data: any) {
    const actionObj = {
      action,
      data,
    }
    this.onTableActionClick.emit(actionObj);
  }
}
```

And this below code is my HTML section. In this section how can i make the whole row clickable. I have tried few ways but it doest work at all. I want to make it clickable using its column key if there is any possibility.

```
 <table class="table table-hover customtable group-table" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortDisableClear>

      <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column.key" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [disabled]="!column.isSort" matTooltip='{{column.title}}' disableClear width='{{column.width}}'> {{column.displayName}} </th>
        <!-- <td *matCellDef="let ele">No</td> -->
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [style.color]="element[column.key]"> ---> I want to make this table data clickable
          <span *ngIf="!column.type" [innerHTML]="element[column.key]"></span>
          <!-- for customized cells -->
          <i *ngIf="column.isInfo && element[column.key]" [matTooltip]="element[column.key]"  matTooltipClass="example-tooltip" class="fa fa-info-circle infoIcon"></i>
          <span *ngIf="column.type && column.type!='date' && column.type!='decimal' && column.type!='roundspan' && column.type!='togglespan'" [innerHTML]="element[column.key] | status:column.type "></span>
          <span *ngIf="column.type=='date'" [innerHTML]="element[column.key] | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"></span>
          <span *ngIf="column.type=='decimal'" [innerHTML]="element[column.key] |number:'2.2-2'"></span>
          <span *ngIf="column.type=='roundspan'" [innerHTML]="element[column.key] |span"></span>
          
          <span *ngIf="column.type=='togglespan'"><mat-slide-toggle [checked]="element[column.key]" [disabled]="!column.permission" (change)="onToggleClick('toggle',element,column)" ></mat-slide-toggle></span>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Actions" *ngFor="let column of extraColumns">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [disabled]="true" matTooltip='{{column.title}}' width='{{column.width}}'>Actions</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <button *ngFor="let a of actionButton" class="tbactionbtn" 
               (click)='onActionClick(a.key, row)' title="{{a.displayName}}">
                <i class="{{a.class}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
    </table>
```

Columns in Ts.file

```
displayedColumns: Array<any> = [
    { displayName: 'First Name', key: 'firstName', isSort: true, class: '', width: '15%' },
    { displayName: 'Last Name', key: 'lastName', isSort: true, class: '', width: '15%' },
    { displayName: 'Physician Name', key: 'physicianName', isSort: true, class: '', width: '15%' },
    { displayName: 'Gender', key: 'gender', class: '', width: '10%' },
    { displayName: 'MRN', key: 'mrn', class: '', width: '15%' },
    { displayName: 'Age', key: 'age', class: '', width: '10%' },
    { displayName: 'Status', key: 'testApprovedStatus', class: '', width: '15%' },
    { displayName: 'Completed Date', key: 'updatedDate', class: '', width: '10%' },
    { displayName: 'Actions', key: 'Actions', class: '', width: '10%' },

  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually with structural directives (directives that start with *) the element that they are applied on is wrapped with `<ng-template>` which means that it's being used as a template. In the case of `<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>` the `tr` will act as a template which means that for every item in you data array (dataSource) you will have a new `<tr>` . If you add the click listener on the `tr` element you should be able to handle the row click event.

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;" (click)="rowClickHandler({ rowData: row, event: $event })"></tr>
```

The column keys are something that you can access inside the rowClickHandler function implementation since they are a property on the component instance. I'm unsure how helpful a column key would be for handling a row click so I assume that having the row data contained in the `row` template variable will provide enough information for handling the click event.

Comment: thanks i have fixed the issue. I have one question how can i make only Display column FirstName and LastName  key hyperlink. I have added my displayedColumns  in the question

Comment: is there any possibility